# Question on derivative of a function

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, dynamical-systems

I have this exercise :

> We consider  the system :
>
> $$\begin{aligned}x_1'=&x_2 \\ x_2'=&-h_1(x_1)-x_2-h_2(x_3)\\ x_3'=&x_2-x_3\end{aligned}$$ where $h_1$ et
>   $h_2$ are locally lipschitz, $h_i(0)=0$ and $yh_i(y)>0$ for all $y\neq0, \; (i=1,2).$
>
> (a) Show that the origin is the unique equilibrium point of the system .
>
> (b) Show that the functional $$V(x)=\int_0^{x_1} h_1(y) dy
> +\frac{x_2^2}{2}+\int_0^{x_3}h_2(y) dy$$ is positive definite for all $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \mathbb{R}^3$
>
> (c) Show that the origin is asymptotically stable

For (a) and (b) that's ok , but to answer (c) i must  calculate $V'$.

And i have a probleme with $V'$.

Can someone help me to find $V'$?

Please help me

Thank you .

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: please who is $f_x (x,t)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

First look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign if you are not sure of how to differentiate V(x) w.r.t $x_1$ or $x_2$ etc.

Then,

$V'(x) = \nabla V(x).f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is the r.h.s of your system. 
i.e. $f(x)=[x_1' \: x_2' \:  x_3']^T$

And $\nabla V(x)= [\frac{\partial(V)}{\partial x_1} \: \frac{\partial(V)}{\partial x_2}  \: \frac{\partial(V)}{\partial x_3}]^T $

Comment: so $V'= \frac{\partial V}{\partial {x_1}}x_1'+\frac{\partial V}{\partial {x_2}}x_2'+\frac{\partial V}{\partial {x_3}}x_3'$ right ? ,we dont derive over y ?

Comment: y is the variable that gets integrated (i.e. it is a dummy variable), so yes, you don't differentiate w.r.t y

Comment: $V'=- h_2(x_3)x_3-x_2^2 $?